# Storing Relational "Type" or "Category" Data in Firebase Without the Need to Update Multiple Locations

Tags: firebase

I am trying to get a good grasp of how to structure relational data in Firebase. I understand that the data model is very different, but I have a long history with relational databases. Today, I am trying to solve a simple problem.

In MySQL, I have a Node table and a NodeType table:

**Node Table**

- Node Id
- Node Name
- Type Id

**Node Type Table**

- Type Id
- Type Name
- Type Metadata

My problem is that I want to store a certain set of metadata for each Node Type, but I only want to store that in one place. I want to be able to change the metadata for **Node Type A**, and have it automatically apply to all Nodes that belong to that type.

What is the best way to structure this in Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post has some ideas on how to restructure relational data in Firebase: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html, I recommend reading it to better understand the problem.

For your specific use-case, you should simply be able to store the nodes and node types under separate top-level keys and reference node types in the node metadata. For example:

/nodes
  /
    name: 
    type: 
/types
  /
    name: 
    metadata:

You can use the `push` method to automatically generate IDs for nodes. For node types, you can use the same push method, or provide manual IDs for the types.

```js
var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/");
ref.child("types").child("type-a").set({name: "Type A", metadata: "About Type A"});
ref.child("nodes").push({name: "Some node", type: "type-a"});
```

You can retrieve type information for a specific type by using `.once('value')`:

```js
ref.child("types/type-a").once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Metadata for Type A is: " + snapshot.val().metadata);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anant. That makes sense. It is hard to accept the fact that I must do two "queries" to get the node and it's type metadata because I have been bound to the relational model for so long. Is that a common pattern for storing references to other locations in Firebase? Will this model adversely affect application performance?

Comment: Yes, agreed that it doesn't feel right to do two queries, but it's standard practice for "NoSQL" stores, Firebase included. We're working on a "v2" of our API that will hopefully have some utilities to ease this process - please keep your feedback coming!