# Query data from firebase Array

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase users tree has this structure:

users:

```
{
 {
 'userName': 'abc',
 'userEmail' : 'abc@abc.com',
 'userPreferences': 
   [ 
     0:'Cinema', 
     1:'It' 
   ] 
  },
  {
 'userName': 'abc',
 'userEmail' : 'abc@abc.com',
 'userPreferences': 
   [ 
     0:'Cinema', 
     1:'Music' 
   ] 
 }
 }
```

Then, I try to find all users that their preference list contain 'Cinema'.
I try this code:

```
var ref1 = new Firebase("https://event-application.firebaseio.com/users"); 
$scope.user = $firebaseArray(ref1.orderByChild("userpreferences").equalTo('Cinema'));
console.log($scope.user);
```

But I don't get the best result. I get this record: 
[image]

Comment: What does *"I don't get the best solution"* means ?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON structure shows preferences as userPreferences, so wouldn't the following work?

```
var ref1 = new Firebase("https://event-application.firebaseio.com/users"); 
$scope.user = $firebaseArray(ref1.orderByChild("userPreferences").equalTo('Cinema'));
console.log($scope.user);
```

However I think there is also another problem with your code, you're called an `.equalTo('Cinema')` however you're comparing it to an array, correct me if i'm wrong but I don't think the behaviour of `.equalTo('Cinema')` is to loop through each of the values and compare them, I think it's just a straight up comparison

If this is the case, you may need to build a custom query by reading the data from firebase and manipulating it via function available to a snapshot

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my post. Yes that was my problem  i don"t find how to compare  .equalTo('Cinema')  with array. And i must keep the same data structure

Comment: @SihemHcine Would you like me to go into reading data from firebase?

Comment: yes of course Sir. Could you give me your mail please

Answer (score 1):

In NoSQL you'll often end up with a data model that reflects the way your application uses the data. If you want to read all the users that have a preference for Cinema, you should model that in your tree:

```
users: {
   'uid-of-abc': {
     'userName': 'abc',
     'userEmail' : 'abc@abc.com',
     'userPreferences': [ 
        0:'Cinema', 
        1:'It' 
     ] 
   },
   'uid-of-def': {
     'userName': 'def',
     'userEmail' : 'abc@abc.com',
     'userPreferences': [ 
       0:'Cinema', 
       1:'Music' 
     ] 
   }
},
"preferences-lookup": {
  "Cinema": {
     "uid-of-abc": true,
     "uid-of-def": true
  },
  "It": {
     "uid-of-abc": true
  },
  "Music": {
     "uid-of-def": true
  }
}
```

Now you can find out what users prefer cinema with:

```
ref.child('preferences-lookup/Cinema').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(userKey) {
    console.log(userKey.key()+' prefers Cinema');
  });
});
```

This is covered in this [blog post on denormalizing data with Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html), in the [Firebase documentation on structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-indices) and in dozens of answers here on Stack Overflow. A few:

- [Storing Relational "Type" or "Category" Data in Firebase Without the Need to Update Multiple Locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478213/storing-relational-type-or-category-data-in-firebase-without-the-need-to-upd)
- [Get Firebase items belonging to category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922271/get-firebase-items-belonging-to-category)
- [Retrieve data based on categories in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709793/retrieve-data-based-on-categories-in-firebase)
- [How to query firebase for property with specific value inside all children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272919/how-to-query-firebase-for-property-with-specific-value-inside-all-children)

Comment: Thank you Sir for your anwer :). But in my application  structure(code) i have not to define preference for Cinema.